# Что написать на Python?

Tags: python

Изучаю Python ~ месяц. Подскажите идею для проекта, чтобы потом залить на github. Что-нибудь нужное типа библиотеки, приложения etc. gui-tkinter

Comment: Если вы изучаете python месяц, то потренируйтесь пока "на кошечках". Особенно, если сами не в состоянии придумать себе проект.

Comment: напиши утилиту для поисках одинаковых изображений на компьютере

Answer (score 2):

Напиши генератор треугольника Серпинского. Это и красиво, и ничего ложного. Ознакомишься с циклами, с рендерингом, с фракталами. Способ построения треугольника на листе бумаги довольно прост, легко гуглится.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю написать то, что необходимо для вас. Я допустим тоже изучал Python и столкнулся с проблемой что написать.

1 - ое написал программу для автоматизации звонком по клиентам. Мне каждый месяц присылают детализацию звонков по компаниям в одном общем файле. Я в ручную каждый месяц раскидывал клиентам. Теперь все автоматизированно делает программа.

2-ое написал программу для копирования файлов. Да конечно, много утилит есть для копировании, но это программа вам поможет усвовить очень много тем, работа с файлами, работа с визуалом, допустим Progress bar прикрутить, поймете как работает буфер. Может быть захотите использовать потоки. Так же, работать с ini файлов, для того что бы сохранять настройки. Идеи будут приходит во время реализации, как усложнить (научиться) текущую задачу.